# pcapsipdump not saving capture files

Tags: svn, voip, wireshark, pcap

i am trying to use a program called pcapsipdump but no matter what i try it dose nothing.  not sure what i am doing wrong.

i installed it from the SVN using this method.

```
    apt-get install subversion libpcap0.8 libpcap-dev build-essential
    svn checkout svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/pcapsipdump/code/trunk pcapsipdump-code
    cd pcapsipdump-code
    make all
    make install-debian
    update-rc.d pcapsipdump defaults
    nano /etc/default/pcapsipdump
```

the settings file looks like this.

```
    PCAPSIDUMP_ENABLE=true
    DEVICE=eth3
    SPOOLDIR=/var/spool/pcapsipdump
    RETENTION=7
```

the process seems to be running

```
    sudo service pcapsipdump status
    pcapsipdump (pid 1457) is running

    ps -ax | grep pcapsipdump
    1457 ttyS0    S      0:00 /usr/sbin/pcapsipdump -d /var/spool/pcapsipdump -i eth3
    1617 ttyS0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto pcapsipdump
```

it seems to be accessing the required libraries.

```
    sudo lsof | grep pcapsip
    pcapsipdu 1457            root  cwd       DIR              252,0     4096    8653224 /var/spool/pcapsipdump
    pcapsipdu 1457            root  rtd       DIR              252,0     4096          2 /
    pcapsipdu 1457            root  txt       REG              252,0    28832   24260551 /usr/sbin/pcapsipdump
    pcapsipdu 1457            root  mem       REG                0,7               10167 socket:[10167] (stat: No such file or directory)
    pcapsipdu 1457            root  mem       REG              252,0  1071552    4980955 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so
    pcapsipdu 1457            root  mem       REG              252,0  1845024    4980944 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
    pcapsipdu 1457            root  mem       REG              252,0    90080    4980754 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
    pcapsipdu 1457            root  mem       REG              252,0    56016    4980988 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0.6.0
    pcapsipdu 1457            root  mem       REG              252,0   979056   24253260 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
    pcapsipdu 1457            root  mem       REG              252,0   249096   24255058 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcap.so.1.5.3
    pcapsipdu 1457            root  mem       REG              252,0   149120    4980942 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
    pcapsipdu 1457            root    0u      CHR               4,64      0t0       8214 /dev/ttyS0
    pcapsipdu 1457            root    1u      CHR               4,64      0t0       8214 /dev/ttyS0
    pcapsipdu 1457            root    2u      CHR               4,64      0t0       8214 /dev/ttyS0
    pcapsipdu 1457            root    3u     pack              10167      0t0        ALL type=SOCK_RAW
```

wireshark seems to work just fine on this system.  i have no idea what im doing wrong.

here is some more info about the system

```
   cat /proc/version
   Linux version 3.13.0-44-generic (buildd@lamiak) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #73-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 16 00:22:43 UTC 2014

   cat /etc/*-release
   DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
   DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
   DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
   DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS"
   NAME="Ubuntu"
   VERSION="14.04.1 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
   ID=ubuntu
   ID_LIKE=debian
   PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS"
   VERSION_ID="14.04"
   HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
   SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
   BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!  also this is my first post here, if i am missing any rules please let me know. Thank you.

EDIT 1:

some more info on the system.  the box has 4 Ethernet ports.  eth2 and eth3 are in br1 using brctl tools.  the port that is being pcapsipdump is a trunk port between 2 switches.  the box is between them.  all traffic is going through the machine.  is there a possibility that the vlans are interfering with the application?

```
     sudo brctl show
     bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
     br0             8000.0050c22508bc       no              eth0
                                                             eth1
     br1             8000.0050c22508be       no              eth2
                                                             eth3

    br1       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:c2:25:08:be
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:175550 errors:0 dropped:11309 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
              RX bytes:10625462 (10.6 MB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

    eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:c2:25:08:be
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:379365 errors:0 dropped:520 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:318668 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
              RX bytes:244877902 (244.8 MB)  TX bytes:40942935 (40.9 MB)
              Interrupt:18 Memory:dfc00000-dfc20000

    eth3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:c2:25:08:bf
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:320221 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:378233 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
              RX bytes:41042572 (41.0 MB)  TX bytes:244621993 (244.6 MB)
              Interrupt:19 Memory:dfb00000-dfb20000
```

EDIT 2:

yep that was it.  tested using a mirrored port instead of passing all vlans through the box. and it started working

now there is the question, is there a way to make this work with vlans? or am i stuck?

Comment: Is /var/spool/pcapsipdump completely empty? Since this tool dumps SIP control traffic, are you generating some? If you sniff with wireshark, does wireshark show that traffic correctly for port 5060?

Comment: yes the directory is complacently blank.  the sip is 5060 almost pure sip at that.  and they do show in normal wireshark.  i have some more setup info to add to this. ill edit my main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capturing on a parent interface of one or more 802.1Q sub-interfaces is supported since SVN revision 101:

http://sourceforge.net/p/pcapsipdump/code/101/

See here how to install latest development version from SVN:

http://pcapsipdump.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Hey @Aex Aey. Welcome to S.O. Please add some context to your links. If those links break in the future, they'll be useless. Refer to section **Provide context to links** from http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for more details about that.

Comment: wow @Aex Aey thank you,  it looks like your the author to the patch?  ill update the SVN asap and test,  ill post here the results of my test.

Comment: hey @Aex Aey. i got  side tracked to another project.  it may be a few years late but that fix did work.

Answer (score 1):

pcapsipdump dose not support vlans it seems.  i cant seem to find any documents to prove or disprove this except the evidence of testing.

SOLUTION:  capture with wireshark and strip the vlan tags out. send capture files to pcapsipdump for processing.

found some tools for re-writing capture files here

```
    http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/wiki/tcprewrite
```

striped out the tags

```
    ls | xargs -I pcapfile tcprewrite --enet-vlan=del --infile=/wireshark/wireshark3/pcapfile --outfile=/wireshark/calls/pcapfile
```

then pushed the capture files into pcapsipdump

```
    ls | xargs -I pcapfile pcapsipdump -r /wireshark/calls/pcapfile
```

and everything worked. just need to add some scripts to do this from time to time.